# Check for an equivalence relation on the integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given the set of integer $\mathbb Z$, define $\sim$ as $x\sim y$ precisely when $2$ divides $x-y$.

I'm having a hard time showing that the three properties of an equivalence relation hold.

Any help is appreciated.

---

*(added from comments)*

I have  $$x-y=2n $$for all n in the set of integer $$y-x=2m $$for all m in the set of integer... Intuitively, there is a connection involving, $$(x-y), (y-x) \text{ and } 2$$  $$y-x= (something) - (x-y)$$ I'm not sure how to proceed forward

Comment: Which of the three properties is giving you trouble?

Comment: It's not exactly the property but the algebraic manipulation. Instead of having to "try" different manipulation, I'm hoping for a surefire way.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. The "surefire way" is to check that each of the three properties holds.

Comment: I understand but the transitivity and symmetric property requires manipulation of algebra

Comment: Everything requires manipulation of algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, reflexivity is easy since for any $x$, $x-x=0$ and we know $2\mid 0$ since $0 = 2 \cdot 0$.

For symmetry, how can you use the fact that $x-y=-(y-x)$? Hint: suppose $2\mid y-x$. Then $y-x=2k$ for some integer $k$ (by the definition). Can you find another integer $\ell$ such that $x-y=2\ell$? What does this tell you?

For transitivity, you assume $2\mid y-x$ and $2\mid z-y$. Write equations corresponding to those inequalities and try to reach the conclusion that $2\mid z-x$. Hint: something will cancel when you add the two equations. For instance, the equations become $y-x=2k$ and $z-y=2\ell$ for some integers $k,\ell$. You can add these equations to get a new relationship.

**EDIT:** Let's work through the definition of the relation. To say that $2\mid y-x$ means that there *exists* an integer $n$ such that $y-x=2n$. This is the definition. Now, if you're proving symmetry, you first start by assuming $x\sim y$, which means $$y-x=2n$$ for an integer $n$ (this is exactly the definition above. Multiplying the above by $-1$ gives $$x-y = -2n.$$ You're absolutely right that $-2n\neq 2n$ - but we don't need this to happen to have $y\sim x$ which is what we're trying to prove. For $y\sim x$ to be true, we must have $x-y=2m$ for some integer $m$. But we know that $x-y=-2n$ which can be written as $$x-y=2(-n).$$ But $-n$ is also an integer, so we can pick $m = -n$. Plugging this in we get $$x-y=2m$$ and so $y\sim x$.

Comment: I have commented above.

Comment: I have 
$$x-y=2n $$for all n in the set of integer
$$y-x=2m $$for all m in the set of integer
Intuitively, there is a connection involving, $$(x-y), (y-x) and 2$$

$$y-x= (something) - (x-y)$$
I'm not sure how to proceed forward

Comment: If you're attempting to do symmetry, if you have $$x-y=2n$$ then multiplying each side by $-1$ gives $$y-x=-2n = 2(-n)$$ since $-(x-y)=y-x$. Now, note $-n$ is also an integer so you can take $m=-n$.

Comment: What I had is 
$$x-y=2n$$
and for $$y~x$$, we have
$$-1(x-y)=(y-x)=-2n$$
But -2n does not equal 2n, thus the symmetric property fails to hold.

Comment: Oh, okay. Let me explain something conceptually in an edit, just a second.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy that $2|x-x$ and if $2|x-y$ then $2|y-x$;
let $2|x-y$ and $2|y-z$ we should have $2|x-z$:
By assumption $x-y=2n$ and $y-z =2m$. So $x-z=(x-y)+(y-z)=2(n+m)$

Comment: @user: $x-y=2n$ then $y-x=2(-n)$. Note that if $n\in \mathbb Z$ then so is $-n$

Comment: Could you explain the "-n"?
Edit: I see why

Comment: So since 2n is not equal to -2n, does it suffice for me to conclude that the equivalance relation does not hold for symmetric property?

Comment: Both are divisible by $2$, so the relation as defined holds.

Comment: No! you need an *arbitrary* element to have 2|y-x